# Excel: How to add one column with another column, row by row?

Tags: excel

So basically, I have two columns, in two different worksheets that I need to add together.

This may be best explained with an example:

```
WORKBOOK 1
              A              B         
      _____________________________
   1 |    Unique ID    |  Number   
   2 |         B1      |    2    
   3 |         C0      |    10  
   4 |         D9      |   N/A   
   5 |         9L      |    0   
   6 |         12      |    5  


WORKBOOK 2
              A              B         
      _____________________________
   1 |    Identifier    |   Price   
   2 |         Q9       |   $10.00    
   3 |         9L       |    $5.00  
   4 |         B1       |  $299.00   
   5 |         C0       |    $0.99   
   6 |         12       |  $100.00
```

The columns in `wordbook 1` are named `unique_id` and `price` and the columns in `workbook 2` are named `identifier` and `number`.

Is it possible to do something such as - If `unique_id` from the first workbook is equal to an `identifier` within the second workbook, multiply the `number` and `price` together. This has to be done for each column/row, and it should somehow either skip or treat the `N/A` as nothing/zero.

Is something like this possible without the use of macros, and just by using a simple function within a cell? Or is there a far better method than what I am thinking of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,[book1]Sheet1!$A:$B,2,FALSE)*B1
```

copied down to suit.

Comment: Everything must be placed within just 1 cell in the `workbook 1`, and not 6 cells unfortunately

Comment: Is that mean you want to find `identifier` corresponding to `unique_id` then multiply `number` by `price`. In the end add all listed elements and sum them up?

Answer (score 0):

This approach will work if your columns are sorted. You may be able to build upon it:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B2:B6,SUMIF(A2:A6,[Book2]Sheet1!$A$2:$A$6,[Book2]Sheet1!$B$2:$B$6))
```

The resulting value is 1107.90